# Property group in custom control

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

What I want is a property that like Font property, it has "Name", "Size", "Unit", "Bold" and the other property in it. I tried the solution in the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755391/group-properties-in-a-custom-control) but it doesn't work...

I tried the solution like this:

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))> _
Class TestingClass
'Some property here
End Class
```

But it doesn't work... Was there something wrong with the code?

Comment: This is a "it doesn't work!" question with a snippet that makes it impossible to guess what doesn't work.  In its present form it is entirely unanswerable.

Comment: @HansPassant well... I mean, the "properties" window should have a "testing class" property and there's other property here in the property (just like the "font" property, there's "Name", "Size", "Unit" and the other property in it...)... but it doesn't show what I wanted, even the "testing class" property, is not in the "properties" window... (Sorry for my bad english...)

Answer (score 0):

you mean an property of an object?
for example:
a button have an property of forecolor then it can wrote as:
button.forecolor 
to access it?
so what you need is a class (i think so) with some code (i can't write for you.. i'm in VB6...)

see here for code example:
http://developer.51cto.com/art/200910/156822.htm
i think this was what you need...