# Group properties in custom control

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I want to do a class that have properties like font, which will have other properties, such as name, size, unit,bold.I had tried a solution but it isn't working for me.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755391/group-properties-in-a-custom-control) 
Anyone can help? Any help will be appreciated.

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))> _
Class TestingClass
'Some property here
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Font
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Unit As Integer
    Public Property Bold As Boolean
End Class

Public Class TestingClass
    Public Property TestFont As New Font()
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Joel, it works perfectly when I added this code "<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))> _" before the "Font" class, the properties show in the IDE properties window now, thanks a lot for your help. –