# Custom Properties Picturebox control

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

1st attempt at creating a control.
i have a class, that Inherits PictureBox

here are some custom properties

```
    'Properties
<Category("Boarder"), Description("Border Size")>
Public Property BorderSize As Integer
    Get
        Return borderSizeField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        borderSizeField = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property


<Category("Boarder"), Description("Border Color")>
Public Property BorderColor As Color
    Get
        Return borderColorField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        borderColorField = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

<Category("Boarder"), Description("Border Color2")>
Public Property BorderColor2 As Color
    Get
        Return borderColor2Field
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        borderColor2Field = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

If i select "Categorized" in the property grid of the control when i place it on the form, my properties are grouped together.

[image]

However, when i select "Alphabetized" they are not grouped.

Question:
How can i have them grouped when "Alphabetized" is selected. Just like the Location is on the picturebox control

[image]

Comment: Pro tip: when you add an image and the words "enter image description here" are inserted automatically, the idea is that you enter the image description there.

Comment: You seem to have misspelled the `Category` as "Boarder" when it should be "Border". Also, what's the point of providing a `Description` if you're just going to use the property name? You should either provide an actual description or don't set that attribute at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755391/group-properties-in-a-custom-control --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378606/create-an-expandable-group-in-a-property-grid ...

Comment: still learning how to create a control.  like i stated, 1st time trying.!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no grouping there. `Location` is one property and it's displayed in the property list in alphabetical order, just as your properties are. The `Location` property is type `Point` and the `X` and `Y` you're seeing there are properties of that `Point` value, not properties of the `PictureBox`. If you add your own property of type `Point`, you'll see the same thing.

Comment: appreciate the tip.  finally found how to do the "Point" and now that portion works.  Still working on getting values to show on the picture box when values are changed.  Will keep looking for the answer!!

Comment: @Robert, how those properties affect the display of the control would depend on how you have overridden the `OnPaint` method. That would be a different question though, so post a new question specific to that if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the comments on my question.
Find code attached that I finally found searching that will allow my custom properties to be under the "Alphabetized" layout. Thanks to @jmcilhinney for his comment explaining about the "Point" value to get location.
Here is photo of properties so far (more to add)
[Custom Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2SCy.png)

here is code snippets of the (2) classes with the labels, and "Descriptions" etc. for the property window.

```
Public Class NewPictureBox
Inherits PictureBox

Public Sub New()

    Size = New Size(100, 100)
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

    Me.m_properties = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_captiontext = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_captionx = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_captiony = New TextLocation(Me)
    'Me.m_stateReadOnly = New TextLocation(Me)

    Me.m_picturebox = New TextLocation(Me)

    'Borders Fields
    Me.m_borderSizeField = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_borderColorField = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_borderColor2Field = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_borderLineStyleField = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_borderCapStyleField = New TextLocation(Me)
    Me.m_gradientAngleField = New TextLocation(Me)
End Sub

<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public ReadOnly Property Properties() As TextLocation
    Get
        Return Me.m_properties
    End Get
End Property
```

part of Class 2

```
    <ToolboxItem(False)>
    Public Class TextLocation
    Inherits Component
  
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
<Category("Properties"),
     DisplayName("Caption"),
     DescriptionAttribute("Enter text for Caption"),
     ParenthesizePropertyName(False),
     XmlElementAttribute("Caption"),
     EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
     RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)>
Public Property Caption As String
    Get
        Return m_captiontext
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        m_captiontext = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Wow! The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383956/14171304) referred link is exactly what you need to do. Group all the `Border` properties in a class, decorate it with `<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>` attribute, pass the `PicutreBox` instance to it through a parameterize constructor to invalidate the drawing when you change a property, Add a read-only property in your custom pbox class that returns an instance of the grouped-properties class and decorate it with `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` attribute.

Comment: Yes, just took me a little time to figure it out.  as stated, 1st attempt.  will get a better crip on this as i practice my own controls.  appreciate the help!